# How do I set my initial window position in Cocoa emacs?

Tags: emacs, cocoa

I have the following set in my .emacs file:

```
 (if (window-system)
   (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 60)
   (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 50 30))
```

It sets the frame height correctly but not the frame position. I am running:

`GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, NS apple-appkit-949.54)`

EDIT:

The code offered below is not Mac-specific. You'll have to edit it (just ake out any of the `*win*` references. Here's what I used that work. Tweak it to your liking!

```
(setq initial-frame-alist
      `((background-color . ,(face-background 'default))
        (foreground-color . ,(face-foreground 'default))
        (horizontal-scroll-bars . nil)
        (vertical-scroll-bars . nil)
        (menu-bar-lines . 0)
        (top . 50)      ;; This is overridden by my-center-frame later.
        (left . 400)        ;; This is overridden by my-center-frame later.
        (cursor-color . "red")
        (mouse-color . "green")))
```

Comment: What is it doing with your frame position info - is it ignoring it altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Futzing with the initial-frame-alist settings, ala:

http://paste.lisp.org/display/6194

might work. Specifically, try playing with the top and the left properties.

Comment: This worked perfect. +50 to you.

Comment: I get `Symbol's value as variable is void: my-win32`

Answer (score 3):

You're using `if` incorrectly, the code you pasted will only run the first form if the condition is true (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html)). Try using the `when` macro instead:

```
(when (window-system)
  (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 60)
  (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 50 30))
```

This will run each form after the condition if the condition is true.